# Check Firebase phone auth limit programmatically?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Is there any way to check Firebase phone auth limit programmatically?

I am trying to add phone verification in my app. I'm currently in free tier, i know the limit is 10000/month. Is there any way to check if the phone auth limit is reached and if not then show users a dialog to enter their phone number.

To explain what I'm trying to achieve using code-

```
if(!_firebase.phoneAuth.limitReached()){

Dialog ("Verify your phone number"),

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API to get the number of verification calls made this cycle, or left within your quota.

Once you exceed the quota, calls to verify the phone number will fail with a "quota exceeded" message. If you regularly see this in your crash report, consider upgrading to the paid plan to raise the quota.